# what should I do to make "io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry" object autowired

Tags: java, spring, prometheus

I'm trying to use MeterRegistry object in the constructor, but Intelij show me a message  `Could not autowire. No beans of 'MeterRegistry' type found.`

[image]

I'm using this dependency:

```
implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-prometheus', version: '1.3.5'
```

I have these properties in application.properties file

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
```

so I'm wondering why it's not autowired by Spring ? what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing actuator JAR:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

For maven use:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for this!